# How to get parameter value in controller called using redirect function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper, codeigniter-form-helper

I have  started with codeingniter, I am calling controller using redirect() function with parameter, how can I get the parameter value in controller.php?

view.php

```
$para array(
             'id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name
);

redirect('login_controller/get_permissions/'.$para);
```

I need $para value in controller.php, how can I get value of $para?

login_controller.php

```
   class Login_controller extends CI_Controller
   {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function get_permission()
        {
            $get_para = $_GET['para'];
            echo $get_para;
        }
    }
```

it's not working :(

Comment: Is it possible to pass array to redirect url? and also you are concatenating array with string directly.

Comment: seesion is best for your issue

Comment: $para=array(
             'id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name
); check the equal to sign i think you have not used or did you miss to type it ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced this code:

```
$para array(
         'id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name
  );
 $this->session->set_flashdata('para',$para);

redirect('login_controller/get_permissions);
```

to

```
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('session');

    $para array(
             'id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name
      );

    $CI->session->set_flashdata('para',$para);

    redirect('login_controller/get_permissions);
```

Its working now...

Answer (score 3):

```
    $id='vlaue';
    $name='name';    
    redirect('login_controller/get_permissions/'.$id.'/'.$name);
```

and then

```
    function get_permission($id,$name)
      {
          echo $id;
         echo $name;
      }
```

But If you want to send array then set_flash Data would be good

```
$para array(
         'id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name
  );
 $this->session->set_flashdata('para',$para);

redirect('login_controller/get_permissions);
```

And then

```
    function get_permission()
      {
         print_r( $this->session->flashdata('para'));
      }
```

See more [Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Fatal ERROR, Using $this when not in object context in view.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function get_permission($para)
    {
        print_r($para);
    }
```

Comment: its not working

in browser it showing...

http://localhost/websites/index.php/Login_controller/get_permissions/Array

404 Page Not Found